# How do I connect to Clickhouse locally using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

I am trying to establish a Clickhouse connection from my local machine but I receive an error that `sqlalchemy` does not know how to deal with clickhouse dialect (`Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:clickhouse.native`). However, everything works in JupyterHub.

I cannot use JupyterHub due to large files that I need to upload into the environment.

Here's how I am trying to connect:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import os

ch_host = os.getenv('CH_HOST', default='my_host')
ch_cert = os.getenv('CH_CERT', default='../path/to/cert')
ch_port = os.getenv('CH_PORT', default='my_port')
ch_db   = os.getenv('CH_DB', default='name_db')
ch_user = os.getenv('CH_USER', default='username')
ch_pass = os.getenv('CH_PASS', default='pass')
engine  = sa.create_engine(f'clickhouse+native://{ch_user}:{ch_pass}@{ch_host}:{ch_port}/{ch_db}?secure=True&ca_certs={ch_cert}')

# test connection
print(pd.read_sql('show tables', engine).head(5))
```

Package versions are the following:

```
print(pd.__version__)
print(pl.__version__)
print(sa.__version__)

2.0.3
0.18.10
2.0.19
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: you should register dialect first by importing clickhouse-sqlalchemy
did you run `pip install clickhouse-sqlalchemy` ?

Comment: nah. gonna try it